# Calling the nearest dictionary key less than a certain given value

Tags: python, lambda

I have a dictionary with time values as keys, and I need to retrieve the value associated with those keys. The nature of my program means that I will almost never be able to call on the dictionary with an exact, existing key, so what I want to do is the following: I want to pass a random input value into the dictionary and for the dictionary to find the key that is closest BUT less than the input value, then give me the value tied to that key.

What I've tried so far is a lambda expression that should find the closest key lower than the input, but when I execute it, I find that it doesn't give me the value I expect. Since my actual code is rather long and complex, I built a small test program to observe my results more clearly:

```py
import random as r

my_dict = {0.0: 0, 1.0: 1, 2.0: 2, 3.0: 3, 4.0: 4, 5.0: 5}

value = round(r.uniform(0, 5), 1)
print('Random Value is: ' + str(value))

dict_value = my_dict[min(my_dict, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))]
print('Corresponding Dictionary Value is: ' + str(dict_value))
```

This program successfully generates a random float value rounded to one decimal. When it passes it into the lambda function, it does not give an accurate value in response. For instance, if the random value is 7.7, the corresponding dictionary value returns 3 (which is wrong), a random value of 3.1 returns 3 (which is correct), 4.7 returns 5 (wrong), etc. I can kind of see why this is happening, as I'm subtracting my value from x which would compare the difference of the two numbers to each key. There is also nothing dictating that the closest key must be lower than the input, only to find the closest key to the input in general, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I hope I've been clear, but please ask questions if I am not. Thank you!

Comment: You are fundamentally using the wrong data-structure, you probably want some sort of binary-search based approach

Comment: A dictionary is not the appropriate structure for this data. Dictionaries are only useful when you want to do exact key lookups. I suggest you use some kind of ordered list, and then you can efficiently binary-search for your keys.

Comment: but to fix this, just filter for keys lower than the input

Comment: Yeah, a BST would  be better. The reason it's a dictionary is because the implementation started out in a simpler way, and now as I expand it, dictionary is no longer the ideal method. I will likely just implement a tree structure, but I am still curious about a way to do it with dictionaries in case I'm told I need to keep it, or at least just for fun.

Answer (score 1):

You can utilize `bisect` module and create custom container - with help of `collections.abc`:

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
import bisect

class closest_dict(Mapping):
    def __init__(self, items):
        s = [*sorted(items)]
        self._keys = [i[0] for i in s]
        self._items = [i[1] for i in s]

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        idx = bisect.bisect_left(self._keys, key)

        if idx > len(self._keys) - 1:
            return self._items[-1]

        if abs(self._keys[idx-1] - key) < abs(self._keys[idx] - key):
            return self._items[idx-1]

        return self._items[idx]

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self._keys

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._keys)

my_dict = {0.0: 0, 1.0: 1, 2.0: 2, 3.0: 3, 4.0: 4, 5.0: 5}

d = closest_dict( (k, v) for k, v in my_dict.items() )

for val in [-1.0, 0.0, 0.1, 2.1, 6.0]:
    print('Closest value to key {} is {}'.format(val, d[val]))
```

Prints:

```
Closest value to key -1.0 is 0
Closest value to key 0.0 is 0
Closest value to key 0.1 is 0
Closest value to key 2.1 is 2
Closest value to key 6.0 is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

If your context requires data structures that you presented, you can try something like (dict comprehension for excluding values that are too big):

```
import random as r

my_dict = {0.0: 0, 1.0: 1, 2.0: 2, 3.0: 3, 4.0: 4, 5.0: 5}

value = round(r.uniform(0, 5), 1)
print('Random Value is: ' + str(value))

new_dict = {k:v for (k,v) in my_dict.items() if v<value}
dict_value = my_dict[min(new_dict, key=lambda x:abs(x-value))]
print('Corresponding Dictionary Value is: ' + str(dict_value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

my_dict = {0.0: 0, 1.0: 1, 2.0: 2, 3.0: 3, 4.0: 4, 5.0: 5}
rand_num = round(random.uniform(0, 5), 1)

# This will find the dict key that corresponds to the value you are seeking
index = min(my_dict, key=lambda n: abs(n-value))

# Then just grab the value from the dict
print(my_dict[index])
```

If you do choose to use a different data structure, this technique will still work with a list:

```
keys = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
value = 1.2
target = min(keys, key=lambda n: abs(n-value))
print(target)
```

Alternatively, you could filter out all of the keys in the dictionary that are greater than the given value:

```
value = 2.2
valid_keys = [key for key in my_dict if key <= value]
target_key = max(valid_keys)
answer = my_dict[target_key]
```

You could also use the filter function:

```
value = 1.6
filtered_keys = filter(lambda x: x <= value, my_dict))
target_key = max(filtered_keys)
answer = my_dict[target_key]
```

Update: The filtering examples here will only find the nearest key that is LESS THAN the given value- which is not exactly what you asked for.  I will leave the examples here for anyone in the future searching this question that may find use for them.  For your specific use case, use the first example.